# Drag&Drop and position at dropped coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to drag and drop items from a list of products to a blank container.
When the user finished drag&drop I have to store the location and the used items to db so that I can display this configuration again.

Unfortunately my problem begin in a early stage.
I succeeded in dragging and dropping items from list to container but unfortunately they are displayed in a tabular form and not at the coordinates I assign to them

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ShoppingCart.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var srcElement;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("div .product").each(function () {
                this.addEventListener('dragstart', OnDragStart, false);
            });

            $("div .bag").each(function () {
                this.addEventListener('dragenter', OnDragEnter, false);
                this.addEventListener('dragleave', OnDragLeave, false);
                this.addEventListener('dragover', OnDragOver, false);
                this.addEventListener('drop', OnDrop, false);
                this.addEventListener('dragend', OnDragEnd, false);
            });

        })

        function OnDragStart(event) {
            srcElement = this;

        }

        function OnDragOver(e) {
            e.preventDefault();


            return false;
        }

        function OnDragEnter(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        function OnDragLeave(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        function OnDrop(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var dm = srcElement.cloneNode(true);

            dm.style.Left = e.offsetX;
            dm.style.Top = e.offsetY;
            dm.style.position = "absolute";

            //$(this).append(srcElement);
            e.target.appendChild(dm); 

            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }

        function OnDragEnd(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div draggable="true" id="div1" class="product">
                            <header>Rieker Trekkingsandalen braun</header>
                            <img src="images/monitor.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="div2" class="product" draggable="true">
                            <header>Rieker Trekkingsandalen braun</header>
                            <img src="images/Cart.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="div3" class="product" draggable="true">
                            <header>Rieker Trekkingsandalen braun</header>
                            <img src="images/mouse.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="div4" class="product" draggable="true">
                            <header>Rieker Trekkingsandalen braun</header>
                            <img src="images/speaker.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div class="bag">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

.product {
    height: 300px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #666666;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: move;
}
.bag {
    background-color: green;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Can anyone point me to the problem here?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: dm.style.position = "absolut";
change it with absolute.

Comment: Thx for verry quick response!! Ok, this is obvious ^^ But the behaviour doesn't change after i fixed that

Comment: can you jsfiddle about your code ? Regards

Comment: First I need to figure out what that is since my web skills are verry basic :P

Comment: Well i hope there might be issue regarding to your dropped element, you are not calculating the offset of dropped element. Calculate the dm offsets instead of e.

Comment: and one more thing, your dropbox also should be absolute because if it wouldn't the elments will be added as the hierarchy rather than you want :)

Comment: 1. Even if I set "left" and "top" hardcoded it is ignored
2. Also when I add "position: absolute;" to my ".bag" the behavior doesn't change...

I experimentet whith that since yesterday ;-(

Comment: well then i think you should not do this in a hard way, there is an easy way just have a look

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

on this link there is a detail intro about how to use draggable and droppable. Because apparently there is no issue unless you jsFiddle it.

Answer (score 0):

```
dm.style.position = "absolut";
```

should be

```
dm.style.position = "absolute";
```

Comment: Ok, this is obvious ^^ But the behavior doesn't change after i fixed that. This mistake occurred since I modify this snipped since yesterday :(